# Based on frequency information about a calendar event, how can I check if a given date is during this event?

Tags: java, date, events, time, calendar

I have the following information about an event:

- Start (if it's an all-day event, it's the start date, if not, it's the start time)
- End (if it's an all-day event, it's the end date, if not, it's the end time)
- Frequency: once, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly
- Separation: timespan between two repetitions of an event. For instance, if an event is daily and the separation is 1 day, this means that the event will occur one day, then the next day it won't occur, then it will occur again the next day.
- Count: number of times this event should repeat
- Until: limiting date an event frequency should occur
- All day: if it's an all-day event

My question is: Given an arbitrary date, how can I check if this date is within this event?

Comment: You have to implement a bunch of condition checks here. I would not use the standard time API from Java if it is before Java 8. My recommendation is to start with Joda-Time.

Comment: Isn't "Separation" an outcome, a result of the other inputs (facts) rather than an input/fact itself?